# Lo Sachmod Prat U'klal

Tags: parashas-yisro, vaeschanan

> Don't covet your friend's house. Don't covet the wife of your friend, nor his slave, nor his maidservant, nor his ox, nor his donkey, nor anything that is to your friend (Shemos 20:14).

Once the passuk says "anything that is to your friend," what need is there for the previous items mentioned? I can only assume this is a prat u'klal setup, in which we apply the teaching to all cases. Nevertheless, the specifics are there to teach you something else - see further discussion [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10910/doesnt-prat-uklal-mean-that-there-are-unnecessary-words-in-torah). So what is added by the peratim here?

Note that the same question may be asked on the parallel in Va'Eschanan:

> Do not covet your friend's wife. Do not desire your friend's house, his field, nor his slave, nor his maidservant, his ox, nor his donkey, nor anything that is to your friend (Devarim 5:18).

Comment: Relevant: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71508/8775, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37520/8775.

Comment: Why isn't this a duplicate of the linked question?

Comment: @SAH Given the answer in that question, that the pratim are there for specific teachings, I now ask about the examples by Lo Sachmod. Not a dupe, but rather an amplification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the Mechilta:

> "לא תחמוד בית רעך" - כלל. "ועבדו ואמתו ושורו וחמורו" - פרט. כלל ופרט - אין בכלל אלא מה שבפרט. וכשהוא אומר
>
> `Once the passuk says "anything that is to your friend," what need is there for the previous items mentioned? I can only assume this is a prat u'klal setup` **-->** RIGHT But it is a kelal ufrat ukhlal
>
> "וכל אשר לרעך" - חזר וכלל. אי אתה דן אלא כעין הפרט:‏
>
> `in which we apply the teaching to all cases` **-->** not exactly because it is not a perat ukhlal but a kelal ufrat ukhlal.
>
> The last kelal results in a restricted extension of the perat {and the multiple examples are needed to define a couple of criteria which restricts the kelal} .

מה הפרט, מפורש בדבר שהוא  **קונה ומקנה**  - אף כלל, מפורש בדבר שהוא קונה ומקנה.‏

> אי מה הפרט, מפורש  **בנכסים המטלטלין**  שאין להם אחריות - אף אין לי אלא נכסים המטלטלין שאין להם אחריות? וכשהוא אומר במשנה תורה (דברים ה יח) "שדהו", - מה הפרט מפורש בדבר שהוא קונה ומקנה - אף אין לי אלא בדבר שהוא קונה ומקנה.
>   אי מה הפרט, מפורש בדבר  **שאינו בא ברשותך אלא ברצון בעלים**  - אף אין לי אלא דבר שאי איפשר לבא ברשותך אלא ברצון בעלים? יצא שאתה חומד בתו לבנך או בנו לבתך, או  **אפילו חומד בדבור**? ת"ל (דברים ז כה) "לא תחמוד כסף וזהב עליהם", מה להלן עד שעושה מעשה - אף כאן עד שעושה מעשה:‏

The Mechilta tested several definitions for the restricted extension of the kelal,  the conclusion is ruled in Shulchan Aruch Choshen Mishpat 359,  10:

> כָּל הַחוֹמֵד עַבְדּוֹ אוֹ אֲמָתוֹ, אוֹ בֵּיתוֹ אוֹ כֵּלָיו שֶׁל חֲבֵרוֹ, אוֹ כָּל דָּבָר שְׁאֶפְשָׁר שֶׁיִּקְנֵהוּ מִמֶּנּוּ, וְהִכְבִּיד עָלָיו רֵעִים וְהִפְצִיר בּוֹ עַד  שֶׁלְּקָחוֹ מִמֶּנּוּ, הֲרֵי זֶה עוֹבֵר בְּלֹא תַחְמֹד (שְׁמוֹת כ, יד‏) ‏

Something that you can buy, if you did made an act of acquisition, and the seller was initially opposed to the transaction.

> `what is added by the peratim here?` **-->** buyable,  mobile, which cannot be acquired against the will of the owner... but from other verses we learned that not each of a those criteria is exact.

All this is in the answer of @hazoriz in name of the Rabenu Bechaye. The text of the Mechilta illustrates how to reach the conclusions.

Comment: How is "Beis rei'echa" part of the klal?

Comment: First, that's not the lashon of the Mechilta - lo Sachmod Beis reiecha is the Klal it says. Second, does that not make it a Klal u'prat u'klal u'prat u'klal?

Comment: right the bait is the kelal of the properties. kelal ufrat ukhlal ufrat ukhlal I don't know this kind of limud,  may be... @DonielF

Comment: How is it a Klal? (To my knowledge there is no such limud. That's my point.)

Comment: the Mechilta says kpk,  כלל. "ועבדו ואמתו ושורו וחמורו" - פרט. כלל ופרט - אין בכלל אלא מה שבפרט.      @DonielF

Comment: It says that the entire phrase לא תחמד בית רעך is the Klal

Comment: @DonielF so what? I don't understand your point.

Comment: Why is בית רעך part of the Klal and not just לא תחמד?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53933/discussion-between-kouty-and-donielf).

Comment: @DonielF aruch hashulchan hoshen Mishpat 359.10 and 11 explains it also http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9104&st=&pgnum=384

Answer (score 1):

See [rabajnu bechaya there.](http://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya,_Shemot.20.14?lang=bi)

It seems he says that the details are brought to exclude thing you can get without the knowledge of the owner (that you are permitted and sometimes preferable to want) for example his dautgher (for marriage) or Torah (which you can get without his permission).

> ואמנם מצינו חמדה שהיא מותרת והיא חמדת התורה והמצות וכמו שאמרו רז"ל קנאת סופרים תרבה חכמה, והחמדה והקנאה הזאת היא מותרת ויש לאדם שכר עליה. ובכלל החמדה המותרת הוא מי שחומד בת חברו לבנו דרך נשואין, שהרי שנינו (שמות כ) לא תחמוד בית רעך, כלל (דברים ה) שדהו ועבדו ואמתו שורו וחמורו **פרט מה הפרט דבר שאי אפשר לו לבא ברשותך אלא ברצון ורשות בעליו אף הכלל כן יצא בתו לבנך או בנו לבתך שהוא יכול לבא ברשותך שלא ברשות אביהם**.‏

[image]

Comment: It seems like you're missing the key point - the Mechilta that he and @kouty quote which makes this a Klal u'prat u'klal.