# Should an adoptee mourn his Jewish biological parents?

Tags: halacha, children-parenting, mourning-aveilus, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

I was adopted at birth from a Jewish biological mother into a Jewish adoptive family.  Should I observe mourning for my birth mother when she dies, and otherwise honor her as a parent?  Thank you.

Comment: Adoption has almost no halakhic effect. http://www.jlaw.com/Articles/maternity4.html

Comment: On Mi Yodeya, are we to answer the [Prat or the Klal](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10874/5)?

Answer (score 2):

During some shiurim, our local rav told us that if one has Jewish biological parents, he is required to treat them with the proper respect and to sit shiva for them. I could not find my notes on the subject, so this is from memory only.