# Am I obligated to "honour [my] mother" (if she became a needy widow and) if she had given me up?

Tags: halacha, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

Am I obligated to "honour [my] mother" (if she became a needy widow and) if she had given me up?

If someone was given up by his or her own mother (as in the quote below), is one obligated to "honour your mother" (by which I mean, any and all interpretation of the command to "honour your mother", which includes financial and/or housing support, especially if the mother is a needy widow, later in her life?)

אִם לֹא רָצְתָה הָאֵם שֶׁיִּהְיוּ בָּנֶיהָ עִמָּהּ אַחַר שֶׁגְּמָלָתָן, אֶחָד זְכָרִים וְאֶחָד נְקֵבוֹת, הָרְשׁוּת בְּיָדָהּ, וְנוֹתֶנֶת אוֹתָם לַאֲבִיהֶם, אוֹ מַשְׁלֶכֶת אוֹתָם לַקָּהָל אִם אֵין לָהֶם אָב, וְהֵם מְטַפְּלִים בָּהֶם, אֶחָד זְכָרִים וְאֶחָד נְקֵבוֹת:

Translation: "If the mother did not want her children to be with her after they were weaned, whether male or female, that is her prerogative, and she may give them to their father, or send them to the [care of] the community if they do not have a father, and the community raises them, whether male or female."

https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.82.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

"Possible Duplicate" says somebody, 
[In regards to Torah and Rabbinical writings, how does "honor your father and mother" work when you've been raised in an abusive household?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78248/in-regards-to-torah-and-rabbinical-writings-how-does-honor-your-father-and-mot)

However, the difference between these two postings: one is talking about being raised in an abusive household while knowing one's parents, whereas my posting here is about being given up for adoption, while still a toddler (after being weaned אַחַר שֶׁגְּמָלָתָן), and only knowing of your parent's identity "later in her life".

Comment: more extreme https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78248/759

Comment: There is no obligation to honor your parents financialy at all (not dependent on Behavior)

Comment: All financial help is tzedoko, which you should do family first

Comment: The difference between these two postings: one is talking about being raised in an abusive household while knowing one's parents, whereas my posting is about being given up for adoption, while still a toddler (after being weaned אַחַר שֶׁגְּמָלָתָן), and only knowing of your parent's identity "later in her life".

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36759/should-an-adoptee-mourn-his-jewish-biological-parents would also seem to answer this question as yes. In any case, if even an abusive parent must be *honored* then finding out who she is later in life would not remove the requirement.

Comment: What does the fact that she is a widow have to do with anything? The definition of kavod is helping her with her basic needs, but out of her pocket, not yours (Kiddushin 31).

Comment: @DonielF The definition of kavod is helping her with her basic needs, using her own money? Is this what you just said?

Comment: @ninamag That’s correct. I have a chiyuv to ensure my mother is able to eat, but I don’t have to lay out the money for it, at least from the perspective of kavod. As mentioned above there may have a chiyuv of tzedakah, if the mother is poor enough (<200 zuz).

Comment: BTW a married woman is exempt from Respect of parents

Comment: @hazoriz interesting. why? and source?

Comment: @ninamag Moshe Finstain seems to say because, a married woman by definition is/lives by her husband, if she will go to her parents to respect them she will not be by her husband, source https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.240.17 and halacha 6 here http://www.chabad.org/1181857/

Comment: @hazoriz so if she decides to visit her parents (like anywhere from hardly to sometimes to regularly), she must (at those times) respect her parents?

Comment: @ninamag I guess so, but I can not gareentee it, maybe ask this

Comment: @ninamag or she can leave before doing it ,(for example her father asked her to Bring him a cup of water she can leave home(but if she stays probably she should bring it))